# How to hide/show columns according to user input using django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a table with many columns (and rows), which I render using 
`{% render_table table_all %}` in a html template of my django app. I want to display certain columns and give the user the choice to show additional columns (using f.ex. a checkbox or drop-down menu).

Is this possible with django-tables2? Or do I have to use javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [django-tables2-column-shifter](https://github.com/djk2/django-tables2-column-shifter) suits your needs? It adds some custom Javascript/templating to allow turning columns on an off:

[image: screenshot for django-tables2-column-shifter]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works fine! I just tried it.
(Sorry for the late answer, my bad for not seeing the reply.)